# Yarp load balancing configuration

Tags: ms-yarp

Hi I am building a system with the following configuration.

Cloudflare  ->  Yarp Load balancer  ->  Dot net 6 Blazor web app Docker container.

I am using cloudflare 15 yr Origin certificate.

I have tried the following setup and it works fine.

Cloudflare -> Nginx Proxy Manager -> Dot net 6 Blazor web app Docker container.

My Nginx Proxy Manager has the following configuration.

```
proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

I would like the termination to terminate at the app.

To clarify I don't want to use Nginx Proxy Manager.  Not even sure it can do load balancing.  I want to use YARP.

Can anyone tell me how I replicate the configuration above in YARP.

At the moment my efforts are failing and my Yarp docker container is complaing with the following error.

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner        exception.---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is    invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain at ystem.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)`

As I am using the same certificate (plus root) as my test in NPM I don't think thats the problem.  I think its to do with the X-Forward*

Any help appreciated.

As mentioned I have tried Yarp basic configuration and the app starts up fine. But just doesn't route. I've been using config files but if code is the way to go then so be it.

Comment: What certificate are you using in the backend docker container web app, and how are you configuring it?
From the exception, it sounds like YARP refused to communicate with the backend app because it could not trust its certificate.